# following hazelcast demo does not create cluster but separate instances

Tags: hazelcast

i'm following along "getting started with hazelcast" video on https://hazelcast.org/getting-started/

the presentor downloads the zip, extracts it & starts running the ../demo/console.sh script, which contains:

`java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.7.1.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp`

when i run this, i get:

```
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.config.FileSystemXmlConfig
INFO: Configuring Hazelcast from '/Users/maspen/Documents/work/caching/hazelcast-3.7.1/demo/hazelcast.xml'.
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.1] Prefer IPv4 stack is true.
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.instance.DefaultAddressPicker
INFO: [LOCAL] [dev] [3.7.1] Picked [10.20.10.58]:5703, using socket ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=5703], bind any local is true
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Hazelcast 3.7.1 (20160905 - 1f47990) starting at [10.20.10.58]:5703
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Hazelcast, Inc. All Rights Reserved.
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.system
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Configured Hazelcast Serialization version : 1
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.BackpressureRegulator
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Backpressure is disabled
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Creating MulticastJoiner
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] [10.20.10.58]:5703 is STARTING
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Starting 8 partition threads
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.impl.OperationExecutorImpl
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Starting 5 generic threads (1 dedicated for priority tasks)
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.nio.tcp.nonblocking.NonBlockingIOThreadingModel
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] TcpIpConnectionManager configured with Non Blocking IO-threading model: 3 input threads and 3 output threads
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:45 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:46 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] You probably have too long Hazelcast configuration!
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
    at java.net.PlainDatagramSocketImpl.send(Native Method)
    at java.net.DatagramSocket.send(DatagramSocket.java:693)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastService.send(MulticastService.java:235)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.findMasterWithMulticast(MulticastJoiner.java:174)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner.doJoin(MulticastJoiner.java:62)
    at com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.AbstractJoiner.join(AbstractJoiner.java:135)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.join(Node.java:650)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.Node.start(Node.java:362)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceImpl.<init>(HazelcastInstanceImpl.java:132)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.constructHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:218)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:176)
    at com.hazelcast.instance.HazelcastInstanceFactory.newHazelcastInstance(HazelcastInstanceFactory.java:126)
    at com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(Hazelcast.java:58)
    at com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp.main(ConsoleApp.java:1580)

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.cluster.impl.MulticastJoiner
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] 


Members [1] {
    Member [10.20.10.58]:5703 - 7332a514-f880-455f-be2f-68c2fcad0f23 this
}

Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.instance.Node
WARNING: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Config seed port is 5701 and cluster size is 1. Some of the ports seem occupied!
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.core.LifecycleService
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] [10.20.10.58]:5703 is STARTED
Sep 09, 2016 1:31:47 PM com.hazelcast.internal.partition.impl.PartitionStateManager
INFO: [10.20.10.58]:5703 [dev] [3.7.1] Initializing cluster partition table arrangement...
hazelcast[default] >
```

i then changed:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.7.1.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp
```

to:

```
java -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.7.1.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp
```

and now get no errors.

however, as shown in the video, i should be able to run this script multiple times to create a cluster:

[image]

when i do this, i get separate 'instances':

[image]

i then copied the script file & prepended once command w/ `-server`:

`java -server -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.7.1.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp`

started that & created another script w/ `-client`:

`java -client -Djava.net.preferIPv6Stack=true -cp ../lib/hazelcast-all-3.7.1.jar com.hazelcast.console.ConsoleApp`

the effect was the same as above.

can someone please clue me in as to what is/not happening here?

Answer (score 0):

Your network / computer does not allow creation of multicast sockets. That can have multiple reasons like your account is not allowed to, a firewall prevents creation or others. It's hard to guess the actual reason. If you're on OSX it might work to deactivate the WiFi connection (so you have localhost only). Anyhow that's the reason why your nodes don't connect together - they cannot use multicast to find each other.

To reconfigure the discovery see: http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#discovering-cluster-members and http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.7/manual/html-single/index.html#discovery-spi